# SSO custom header jsp

Tags: jsp, http, http-headers, single-sign-on, custom-headers

I am creating a  test application for SSO login in JSP. For it I need to add the user_name in http header. But I am not able to do in JSP. Could you give some tips/idea/implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately your description is very vague ... what technology/product is used for SSO? How is SSO achived?

Comment: Hi I am using JSP/Servlet for sending a single sign of request to other application which accept the http request. My problem is that I have to provide the "user_id" in HTTP request header from my jsp/servlet page. But there is no way to do in jsp. 
I need to do in java only and product it internal portal to the company.

Comment: Which class/framework sends the request .. HTTPUrlConnection or Apache HTTPclient? Providing the JSP code snippet will certainly shed some light